# Using templates with anonymous classes scoped inside a function

Tags: c++, templates, anonymous-class

Let's say I have the following snippet:

```
template <class T> void f(T arg) { arg(); }

void g()
{
   struct { void operator()(void) { } } foo;

   f(foo);
}
```

Visual C++ accepts this.  However, when I try GCC, I get:

```
$ g++ --version # just in case this matters
g++ (Debian 4.4.5-8) 4.4.5
...
$ g++ foo.cc
foo.cc: In function 'void g()':
foo.cc:7: error: no matching function for call to 'f(g()::<anonymous struct>&)'
```

When `foo` is scoped globally and its type has a name, this works.  But when the type is anonymous *or* declared inside `g()` it does not.

Why does GCC reject this?  Is it valid C++?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

14.3.1 paragraph 2:

A local type, a type with no linkage, an unnamed type or a type
compounded from any of these types shall not be used as a
templateargument for a template typeparameter.

In other words, not valid. Although it would be handy imo, that's maybe why VC allows it.

Comment: frustrating, indeed. This would have been a workable alternative to the lack of closures in C++ for instance.

Comment: Thanks for such a straightforward answer.  To me it seems like this usage fits the "spirit" of the language, but I can also see why this might have been scoped out to save implementers some hassle.

Comment: exactly. It's a pitty one has to clutter the global or other namespaces with structs that don't really belong there but just get used once in a single function..

Comment: you can always use unnamed-namespaces for those kind of functors!

Answer (score 2):

As already said, a local class (a class defined within a function) can not be used as a template argument. Fortunately, C++0x fixes that with lambda functions:  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B0x#Lambda_functions_and_expressions

Comment: I think C++0x even allows local-classes to be used as template arguments!